# how to return json object from controller in laravel to view and perform angular js operation on that

Tags: mysql, angularjs, json, laravel-5.4

4 for my app and trying to access the data from database then change it in to json array and return to the view but i am unable to perform the angular js operation on that.

Here is my controller code

```
public function index(){

        $today=Carbon::now();
       ;

        //$enquiry = Enquiry::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
        $enquiry_status=EnqStatus::select('eid')->where('next_follow_date','=', date("Y-m-d", strtotime($today)))->Where('status','=','Follow Up')->distinct()->get();

        $pending_opn=OPN::where('opn_status','=',0)->get();
        $pending_opn1=OPN::where('opn_status','=',0)->get()->toArray();

        $pending_opns = json_encode($pending_opn1);
        $params=[
            'enquiry_status'=>$enquiry_status,
            'pending_opn'=>$pending_opn,
            'pending_opns'=>$pending_opns
        ];
        return view('admin.admin_dashboard')->with($params);
    }
```

and here is my view code

```
<div class="col-sm-12" ng-app="customInterpolationApp">
                            <?php

                                    //dd($pending_opns);
                            ?>

                                     <li ng-repeat="x in pending_opns">
     // x[0]->id//
  </li>

<script>


  var customInterpolationApp = angular.module('customInterpolationApp', []);

  customInterpolationApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
  });
</script>
```

when i simply print the pending_opns in view like dd($pending_opns);
it looks like

"[{"id":2,"opn_number":2,"eid":69,"company_name":"V-Mart Retail Limited","contact_person_delivery":"","mobile_no":"9350958582","order_no":"","order_date":"19-03-2018","date_of_receipt":"19-03-2018","delivery_address":"Khasra No.43/20/21, 44 Taura Road ,Opp.Ansal API Industrial Area Near GITM Woman College Bilaspur,Gurgaon-122413, Haryana","delivery_date":"","printing":"","belt_or_rope":"","size_color_print":"","amendement_required":"","rate_of_tax":"","form_type":"","pan_no":"","lst_no":null,"cst_no":null,"form_required":"","tin_no":"","billing_address":"Khasra No.43/20/21, 44 Taura Road ,Opp.Ansal API Industrial Area Near GITM Woman College Bilaspur,Gurgaon-122413, Haryana","payment_tearms":"","contact_person":"Mr. Ambesh","contact_mobile_no":"9350958582","octroi_by_us_reimbursable":null,"octroi_by_us_non_reimbursable":null,"octroi_by_party":null,"art_work_attached":"","sign":"","order_of":"","date1":"19-03-2018","remarks":"","opn_status":0,"created_at":"2018-03-19 12:05:51","updated_at":"2018-03-19 12:05:51","created_by":"ADMIN","updated_by":"ADMIN"}] ◀"

Comment: 1st, part of the array you are returning is json_encoded and the other isn't. Is it supposed to?
2nd, you just need to decode on the other end to work it out.

Comment: but i want json object so that i can perform angular js operation easily

Comment: So, you just json_decode and you should be able to read it as an array. what's wrong?